# Como faço para varrer uma string e trazer partes diferentes dela?

Tags: regex, pl-sql, substring

Usando REGEX é possível "concatenar" máscaras para trazer partes diferentes de uma mesma string?

Como faço para varrer uma string e trazer partes diferentes dela?

- Eu tenho um campo de texto com a seguinte informação:

  > 00200.035219/2012-15 (VOLUME 1)
- Quero que o retorno seja exatamente assim:

  > 00200.035219/2012-15;1

A informação que tem depois do ponto e vírgula é sempre referente ao número do volume.

Estou usando PL/SQL e REGEX.

Comment: Consegue retornar subgrupos utilizando regex: https://regex101.com/r/kemtne/1

Comment: @PanterA Muito obrigado! A expressão regular que eu precisava era exatamente essa. Só fiquei com uma dúvida: Qual o método que devo usar para escrever na tela os subgrupos $1;$2?

Comment: Pode utilizar a função [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm). Ex.: `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(field, '([^ ]+) \(VOLUME ([^)]+)\)', '\1;\2') "replaced_field" FROM table`.